# Is there a way to give permission for user group for infopath section

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have a custom list with infopath and there is a section admin can only see and I used the admin list on list and I use admin login for condition, but if it only work for only 8 admin but I am looking for 10 admin.

If there is a way to give permission for user group would be great !

Comment: The section means you have a different web part for an admin content or some portion of the one form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use the following link: its useful:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32515.restrict-infopath-section-visibility-based-on-user.aspx